# Why can't I use fitted in class "ar"?

Tags: r, time-series

I take fit model AR(2) for times series `chuoie`:

```
e      <- c(101,82,66,35,31,7,20,92,154,125,85,68,38,23,10,24,83,132,131,118,
            90,67,60,47,41,21,16,6,4,7,14,34,45,43,48,42,28,10,8,2,0,1,5,12,14)
chuoie <- ts(e)
fit    <- ar.yw(chuoie, order=2)
```

And I want calculated values fitted for model fit AR(2):

```
fitted.values(fit)
```

Then I get:

```
NULL
```

I don't understand the problem. If I use the `forecast` package, fit a model with `Arima(2,0,0)` and use `fitted`, then I will get results with no problems. Can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: Questions about understanding `R` code belong on [SO]. We will migrate this there.

Comment: Did you test for stationarity?

Comment: Yes, this is stationary series - a part of series E in the book "Time series analysis forecasting and control" / Box and Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that no method of `fitted()` exists for that kind of object. The class of `fit` is

```
class(fit)
## [1] "ar"
```

You can list all the methods that are defined for `fitted()` using `methods()`:

```
methods(fitted)
## [1] fitted.default*       fitted.isoreg*        fitted.kmeans*        fitted.nls*          
## [5] fitted.smooth.spline*
## see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

As you see, there is not `fitted.ar`. Also `fitted.Arima` is missing, but this method is defined in the `forecast` package:

```
library(forecast)
methods(fitted)
## [1] fitted.Arima          fitted.arma*          fitted.default*       fitted.fracdiff*     
## [5] fitted.garch*         fitted.isoreg*        fitted.kmeans*        fitted.nls*          
## [9] fitted.smooth.spline*
## see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

This explains, why `fitted()` works with a model of class `Arima`, but not with one of class `ar`.

If you want to get the fitted values for your `ar` object, you can use the residuals that are stored inside the object (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942457/4303162) answer):

```
e - fit$resid
```

(The linked answer uses a plus sign. But the code of `fitted.Arima()` shows that the residuals should be subtractted.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Stibu for attention to my problem. I use R for time series analysis and forecasting.